# How to fix undefined offsets

Tags: php

I have a php notice stating `undefined offset:1` on `line 5` (in this example).

```
 1   private function checkForActiveControllerAndAction($filename, $navigation_controller_and_action) {
 2       
 3       $splitted_filename = explode("/", $filename);
 4       $active_controller = $splitted_filename[0];
 5       $active_action = $splitted_filename[1];
 6       $splitted_filename = explode("/", $navigation_controller_and_action);
 7       $navigation_controller = $splitted_filename[0];
 8       $navigation_action = $splitted_filename[1];        
 9       if ($active_controller == $navigation_controller AND $active_action == $navigation_action) {
 10           return true;
 11       } else {
 12           return false;
 13       }
 14   }
```

What's causing it and how can I prevent this?

Comment: what was `$filename` ?

Comment: The error seems input specific.

Comment: PHP is simply telling you that your result array `$splitted_filename` only has one item.  What this means for your code is that `$filename` has no slashes.

Comment: Understood, thanks. How can I test/catch this so it doesn't create an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you explode the `$filename` the string may not contain a `/` character, which means the whole of `$filename` will remain in the first element of the array (by default).

You should check the length of the array [`count`](https://www.php.net/count) or check if the element exists [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset).

This is what causes the unknown offset error.

Readup on explode here: https://www.php.net/explode

To check if you can access the 2nd index:

```
if (isset($splitted_filename[1])) {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, understood. How would I do that?